# Rails after_save callback creating "stack level too deep" loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a setup where `Chapter`s are placed in a queue via a `has_many` `QueueItem`s relationship.  A single `Chapter` can have many `QueueItem`s, because it might have to go through the revision process a few times before a `QueueItem` gets marked `approved` (which is a boolean).

Each `QueueItem` has a `position` which is just an integer to indicate its place in line.  I am trying to create a method inside either the `chapter.rb` or `queue_item.rb` models that can reorder the queue when an item is approved.

The method (currently inside `queue_item.rb` looks like this:

```
  def reorder_queue
    Chapter.where(should_be_queued: true).order("created_at ASC").each_with_index do | chapter, index |
      chapter.most_recent_queue_item.update(position: index + 1)
    end
  end
```

And it references the `chapter.rb` method for `chapter.most_recent_queue_item`, which is just this:

```
def most_recent_queue_item
    item = QueueItem.where(chapter_id: self.id).last
    item
end
```

The issue I'm having is I need the `reorder_queue` method to be `after_save` when a `QueueItem` is updated.... but the method itself updates `QueueItem`s which throws me into an infinite "stack level too deep" loop.

Can anyone see how I should structure this so I don't get stuck in infinite loops?  I feel like thsi should be a pretty commonplace problem.

Comment: You are trying to update the most_recent_queue_item, which triggers an after_save event which tries to to update the most_recent_queue_item, repeat.  If the position is solely updated here, i'd be tempted to use the queue_item.id as the queue order and call it a day.

Comment: If you have no objection to skipping all callbacks (including the updating of `updated_at`) you could use [`#update_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) e.g. `chapter.most_recent_queue_item.update_column(position: index + 1)`.

Comment: How will it work when race condition occur? Probably you need to lock for update and wrap into transaction your updating. And use single query as "callback" inside that transaction, something like `UPDATE queue_items AS qi SET position = new_positions.new_position FROM (SELECT qi2.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chapters.id) FROM queue_items AS qi2 INNER JOIN chapters ON qi2.chapter_id = chapters.id WHERE chapters.should_be_queued = true) AS new_position WHERE qi.id = new_positions.id`. Need to check how it will work, but this is idea for you

Comment: Your approach looks a bit like de-normalization of the data model, so I'd like to suggest a totally different approach. Basically your position-column just depends on the created_at-column. So why not skip the position-column altogether (with all the asscociated callback-hassles and race conditions as mentioned above) and introduce a scope like has_many :recent_queue_items , -> {where(should_be_queued: true).order("created_at ASC")}. If you really need the position you could use window-functions, if your DB supports that. It's a different approach than yours, but might be worth to consider

Answer (score 0):

you have to skip callbacks so that the code does not get into infinite loop as the callback calls update and update triggers after_save callback

Comment: I would love to!  How do I do that?

Comment: Use update_column instead or update? There are few was. You can search "how to skips callbacks in rails model"

Comment: It's `update_columns` now, but it worked perfectly!  Thanks!